# Nombre de tablas en mayusculas usando anotacion @Column en BD postgree sql

Tags: postgresql, jpa

Tengo JPA importado y linkado a una base de datos y cada vez que levanto la aplicación me genera las tablas y sus respectivas columnas.

El tema es que estoy tratando de respetar las convenciones de tener los nombres en mayusculas de SQL. Pero mediante la anotacion @Column no he sido capaz de obtener el resultado deseado. He probado lo siguiente:

```
@Table(name = "AIRPORTS")
@Table(name = "\"AIRPORTS\"")
```

La segunda sentencia va en base a lo que lei de aquí pero no logro el objetivo

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAE3TBxyjqaQkg55pKdq12LynGwi9a2tU1wk_c3xn%3DWyO-fCa9A@mail.gmail.com

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Esto es con hibernate? de casualidad

Comment: Hola, ¿podrias agregar tú persistence xml?, ¿es un proyecto JAVA EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes configurar la estrategia de nombrado de hibernate, por ejemplo si estás usando spring en tu application.properties se debe colocar:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

En la documentación encuentras más sobre el tema
[Hibernate Domain Model](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naming) especificamente en [PhysicalNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy) donde se explica que se debe usar ésta clase cuando las convenciones de nombrado utilizadas por la organización tiene sus particularidades, por ejemplo que todas las entidades tengan un acrónimo al inicio.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, añadiendo lo sugerido más escapando las comillas en la declaración del string funciona